# How to structure/design a Web App maximizing reusability for AJAX/Inline Edits

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, web-applications

How can I structure/design my web application such that I can reuse code for AJAX/Inline edits. I use MVC (Zend Framework). There are parts that already facilitate reusability

- Views/Layouts - I can disable layout (the "page template" containing `<html><head>` & stuff) just serving the view partial for that action for use in AJAX dialogs
- But for Inline edits, I need to serve smaller parts, just the textbox. Furthermore, I need a special action to handle the request (eg. `updateName()` instead of `updateUser()`)?

What is the way of designing my app to maximize re usability?

Comment: check ZF documentation about contextSwitch, to get specialized views (and actions) for xml/json partial html content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `contextSwitcher`. A quick example

```
// In side your controller class
public function init()
{   
    // Obtain the contextSwitcher
    $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');

    // Add two new contexts, remove which will be JSON and view which will be HTML
    $ajaxContext->addActionContext('remove', 'json')
    ->addActionContext('view', 'html');

    // Init the context
    $ajaxContext->initContext();    
}
```

You then need to define the two actions `remove` and `view`

`remove` is going to return all the view variables in a JSON encoded array which your javascript can parse and use, you therefore do not need a view script. An action using a context like JSON or HTML will automatically have its layout disabled.

```
public function removeAction()
{
     // Do some operations here for removing data, and I'll assume you assign the outcome to $success

     if($success)
          $this->view->message = "Success";
     else
          $this->view->message = "There was a problem removing your data";
}
```

You would access the `remove` action by using a URL like `/index/remove/format/json` - without the format json the request will fail.

Your HTML action `view` will need a view script, here is the action

```
public function viewAction()
{
     // Load something from the database and assign to $data
     $this->view->name = $data['name']
}
```

Your view script will be called `view.ajax.phtml` this will contain your output for the `view` action, you would access the view action on URL like `index/view/format/html`.

The view script may look like this

```
<h1>Hello <?=$this-escape($this->name)?></h1>
<p>Welcome to my site. This was obtained via an AJAX request.</p>
```

Remember to read the [docs on the contextSwitcher](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) as I may have missed something.

I hope that helps.